# Using Stirling's formula, show that limit is equal to zero

Tags: limits, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Let $\lambda\in(0,1)$,
$h=\lfloor(i+1)\lambda\rfloor $.
Show
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty}\binom{i}{h}(1-\lambda)^{(i-h)}\lambda^{h}=0
$$

I was able to prove that for $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ using approximation for central binomial coefficent
$\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$. But not the other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First note that $h\to \infty$ and $i-h\to \infty$ as $i\to \infty$.
Apply the Stirling approximation for the binomial
$$ \binom{i}{h} =\frac{i!}{h! (i-h)!}\approx 
\sqrt \frac{i}{2 \pi h (h-i)} \left(\frac{i}{i-h}\right)^i  \left(\frac{i-h}{h}\right)^h $$

And write $h=(i+1)\lambda-\epsilon$ with $0\le \epsilon <1$, replace and evaluate the limit.